# EJS ForEach loop tag

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to increment a class name for a specific html tag while using a forEach loop inside express - EJS..

```
            <a href="./post" class="article featured-article featured-article-1">
                <img src="/images/<%= row.image %>" alt="" class="article-image">
                <span class="article-category"><%= row.title %></span>

                <div class="article-data-container">

                    <div class="article-data">
                        <span><%= row.date %></span>
                        <span class="article-data-spacer"></span>
                        <span><%= row.date %></span>
                    </div>

                    <h3 class="title article-title"><%= row.title %></h3>

                </div>
            </a>
       <% }); %>
```

I need the  tag to increment 3 times on the "featured-article-1" class. so it would loop through the code 3 times, and each time the class would read "featured-article-1", "featured-article-2", "featured-article-3"

I have tried all sorts to figure this out, but unable to. My whole content displays 3 times in the view source, but all display "featured-article-1" - my CSS grid is designed in a way that i need to be able to rename these classes. - Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your EJS the first line where you specify the FOR LOOP is missing. I added an example with a forEach loop.

To solve your concern just use EJS escaping syntax **<%=**

```
<% data.forEach(function(row,index) { %>
    <a href="./post" class="article featured-article featured-article-<%= index+1 %>">
        <img src="/images/<%= row.image %>" alt="" class="article-image">
        <span class="article-category"><%= row.title %></span>

        <div class="article-data-container">

            <div class="article-data">
                <span><%= row.date %></span>
                <span class="article-data-spacer"></span>
                <span><%= row.date %></span>
            </div>

            <h3 class="title article-title"><%= row.title %></h3>

        </div>
    </a>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Genius.. thank you so much! for some reason the forEach didnt paste in when i did the Q. however, it was the function (row, index) I was missing and the <%= index+1 %> which is what I couldn't figure out for the class name.. thanks again!